# HystrixCommand request getting rejected, default configuration not getting override

Tags: threadpool, hystrix

I am using HystrixCommand for forcing long running query to be timeout. Which is working perfectly fine. Query getting time out with configured time.
But in case of load circuit breaker is getting open and it is started rejecting the request with below error.

Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@59c4b527 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@51cd4319[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 12759]

I tried to override the default configuration provided by  Archaius for threadpool(like corepool size, max pool size, queue size etc.... ). but somehow it is not getting effective. below are my configuration in my application.yml file.

hystrix:
command:
queryTimeOutHandler:
execution:
isolation:
thread:
timeoutInMilliseconds: 600000
threadpool:
queryTimeOutHandler:
coreSize: 200
maximumSize: 200
maxQueueSize: 100
queueSizeRejectionThreshold: 100
allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize: true

So with configuration i was expecting the thread count should be 200. and it should serve 200 request at a time and 100 should be queued. but unfortunately its not happening.

How can i check my configuration in application running in production?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override "execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests"

Please refer below for more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452228