# Getting exception from Hystrix

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

I am using hystrix for spring boot project but getting timeout exception.

Please find below controller code for details

```
@GetMapping("/getData")
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getDataFallBack", commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "60000"), @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE") })
public ResponseEntity<Object> getData() {

}

/**
 * Fallback method for getData
 */
public ResponseEntity<Object> getDataFallBack(Throwable e) {
    LOGGER.info("In fallback method", e)
}
```

While testing with more calls like 1500 hits in 5 min then getting timeout exception. While checking logs then find below logs

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not acquire a semaphore for execution
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleSemaphoreRejectionViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:966) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.applyHystrixSemantics(AbstractCommand.java:554) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$200(AbstractCommand.java:60) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$4.call(AbstractCommand.java:419) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$4.call(AbstractCommand.java:413) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
```

Can someone please let me know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add hystrix property [execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests) and set it to a higher number (200).
The default value of execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests is "10" so the method getData() will be allowed to be executed in parallel for not more than 10 times.

Similarly you need to add [fallback.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#fallback.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests) and set it to 200 for your fall back method.

```
    @GetMapping("/getData")
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getDataFallBack", commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "60000"), 
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE"),@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests", value = "200") })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getData() {
    
    }
```